# Phonegap ios app link not open in native browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in phonegap. Phonegap ios app anchor link not open in native browser. All link open in app.
How to anchor link open in native browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common problem :)

Use [the InApp Browser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen), set the `target` (2nd param) of the `open` funcion to `_system`. That should open the link in the default system browser.

You can now also open links inside the app, in the 'In App Browser' if you like. Pass in `_blank` to achieve that.

Hope that helps,
Eddy

Comment: Can you elaborate? How are you testing it, what's the source code?

Comment: I am tested in iphone. Here is my code  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');"><img alt="" src="img/facebook_icon1.png">
        </a>

Comment: Please check the usage in the link I provided, it's like this: `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options)`, so the second argument must be set to `_system`.